# Как отобразить список скаченных файлов?

Tags: webkit, android, java

В своем приложении с `WebView` я использую скачивание файлов, как показано ниже:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                    long contentLength) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

И мой файл скачивает другая программа, насколько я понял, браузер Android'a. Соответственно, чтобы посмотреть список скаченных файлов, нужно открыть браузер Android'a и в меню выбрать загруженные файлы.

Как я могу отобразить список скаченных файлов в своем приложении? Хотелось бы, чтобы вид страницы скаченных файлов был аналогичен виду страницы скаченных файлов, как в стандартном браузере Android. Было бы удобней всего запустить из моего приложения именно эту страницу в браузере Android, но чтобы пользователь не догадался что было загружено другое приложение.

Answer (score 2):

Можно отслеживать и отображать загрузки в своем приложении. То есть

```
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
        long contentLength) {
    // TODO: Сохранить запрошенный URL в свой список
}
```

А отображать полученный список с помощью ListActivity (его можно стилизовать так, чтобы это было близко по духу к встроенному отображению).

Как вариант можно еще поисследовать возможность прямого вызова Activity, отвечающей за отображение закачек, встроенного браузера Андроида.

Comment: На прямую я не смог вызвать этот список в Андроид веб-браузере.

Идея с отслеживанием загрузок хорошая, я пока так и реализовываю. Но у com.android.browser выводится информация о том, на сколько процентов данный файл загружен, если ли способ и мне узнать такую информацию о степени загрузки файла для её отображения.